# Google Sign In serverAuthCode is getting null

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, google-signin

D/EGL_emulation( 9260): app_time_stats: avg=83219.91ms min=1.44ms max=2329685.50ms count=28

W/Auth    ( 9260): [GoogleAuthUtil] isUserRecoverableError status: NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT

I/flutter ( 9260): Google Access Token: ya29.a0AfB_byBhIKqNK1teL9pzZNxgktKDnX2KhStaxB8X1pmxS0EPGphifjZdmXFHMW5R5-j70PRE-2sYmPIr1EttYQTBsibG89ZGzjOq2b_Nal3G5n3P3QpFI2YAERNnsozvh1Vh0A-BuPuQDAnGeRzY4FFzrzs-gAgeJAaCgYKASMSARASFQHGX2MibSgPlsx9vVc3vLiAkYNKsQ0169

I/flutter ( 9260): Google Server Auth Code:

I/flutter ( 9260): Google Id Token:

I/flutter ( 9260): Google Email: nurain.cubosquare@gmail.com

I/flutter ( 9260): Google Id : 113699528046273182780

```
// Add these imports at the top of your file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInApi {
  static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  ]);

  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() => _googleSignIn.signIn();
}

class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  String googleEmail = '';
  String googleId = '';
  String googlePhotoUrl = '';
  String googleServerAuthCode = '';
  String googleAccessToken = '';
  String googleIdToken = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _handleSignIn();
          },
          child: Text('Sign In with Google'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInApi.signIn().then((userData) {
      if (userData != null) {
        userData.authentication.then((googleKey) {
          setState(() {
            // Retrieve the data from Google auth
            googleEmail = userData.email;
            googleId = userData.id;
            // googlePhotoUrl = userData.photoUrl;
            googleServerAuthCode = userData.serverAuthCode ?? '';
            googleAccessToken = googleKey.accessToken ?? '';
            googleIdToken = googleKey.idToken ?? '';
          });
          print("Google Access Token: $googleAccessToken");
          print("Google Server Auth Code: $googleServerAuthCode");
          print("Google Id Token: $googleIdToken");
          print("Google Email: $googleEmail");
          print("Google Id : $googleId");
          // Call your login function if no errors
          checkInternetAndLoginWithGoogle();
        }).catchError((err) {
          print('Inner error: $err');
        });
      } else {
        print('User cancelled sign in');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error occurred: $err');
    });
  }

  void checkInternetAndLoginWithGoogle() {
    // Implement your login logic here
    // This method will be called after successfully retrieving Google user data
  }
}
```

I have tried this code but still im getting null in serverAuthCode